# Using Google's API through laravel/hybridauth

Tags: php, api, laravel, google-api, hybridauth

I want to create an app that uses Google+ APIs through hybridauth.

I'm using atticmedia/anvard version of hybridauth, that is already configured with Google's clientID and secretKey that have been generated through Google Developer Console (I have inserted these info inside the hybridauth.php file inside the config folder of laravel). I have setted the scope too (as Google suggest).

```
"scope"   => "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
```

I do the following in a laravel route:

```
if (!$hybridauth->isConnectedWith('Google')) {
    $adapter = $hybridauth->authenticate('Google');
}
else {
    $adapter = $hybridauth->getAdapter('Google');
}

$profile = $adapter->getUserProfile();
```

Till now, everything goes well. The profile is correctely printed using the var_dump() function. So I can assume I am logged in. Now I want to make a call to Google APIs (for example [this](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/search)). In the same laravel route, after printing the user's profile, i do the following:

```
$answer= $adapter->api()->api('/people', 'get', array(
                                        'query' => 'Google'
                                    ));
```

As shown in [this](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/userguide/tuts/advanced-access-google-api.html) page, I can use the api() method to do the call. But the only result I can print is "NULL". I suspect that somehow the request is not correct, but I tryed almost anything, and I have not found yet a "real" example of Google API in conjuction with laravel/hybridauth.

Answer (score 0):

When calling `$adapter->api` in `hybridauth` to access Google APIs, you must use the full HTTP URL request.

```
$answer= $adapter->api()->api('https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me');
```

For other services, such as Facebook, you don't need to

```
$answer= $adapter->api()->api('/me');
```

I'm using Laravel 4.2.11 and `hybridauth dev-master`

Reference: http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/userguide/tuts/advanced-access-google-api.html

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I already tested your suggestions, with the same results (that is I already tryed to insert inside the API call the full API address). I'm using Laravel 4.2 too, but i started using the atticmedia/anvard version of hybridauth, and at the present status of development, I think it's not a good idea to start all over from scratch.

Comment: Thank you again. Maybe I can try it in a testing environment. I have already succeeded in logging and using social capabilities in Facebook, Twitter and Linkedin... but Google still remain a problem :(

Comment: Read the code how `HybridAuth` itself handle `Google API`, https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth/blob/master/hybridauth/Hybrid/Providers/Google.php

Comment: I will give it a look. It seems interesting. :)

Comment: I've read this file carefully, but I've found only call to Google's API that not require a parameter. There are only two example that uses a particular form of call with parameter, and that is using the http_build_query() function. I've tryed to make my own calls using this method, even using curl after the creation of the query URL... but I can't obtain what I'm serching for. Have you other tips for me?